# textarea content insertion failed to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post records into database same script was working fine a few days ago after I modify my website, its not working correctly.

When I try to echo the contents then I get everything is working fine. even I tried to insert record without textarea content then it works perfectly only when I try to insert records with content I mean $post_content then i got an error in query.

If I use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, I got the record inserted but without textarea content, its blank, I used `nl2br()` for escaping line break but nothing works totally depressed at this moment, and the same code is working perfectly on my local computer server dont find where the real problem is.

I thought the text editor is causing the problem, I am using niceEdit now, I also tried using tinyMce but never works. Can anyone please help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <title> Insert New Post</title>
        <script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>

        <style>

        input[type="text"]{
            width:90%;
            height: 30px;
        }
        select{
           height: 30px; 
        }
        table{
            width:100%;
        }
        label{
            font-weight:300;font-size:1.5em;text-align: right;
        }
        textarea{
            width: 90%;
        }
    </style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body>
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
 <?php
 ob_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
          $post_title=$_POST['post_title'];
          $post_author=$_POST['post_author'];
          //$post_date=date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
          //$post_date=date("l jS \of F Y");
          $post_catagory=$_POST['post_catagory'];
          $post_image=$_FILES['post_image']['name'];
          $post_image_tmp=$_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
          $post_keyword=$_POST['post_keyword'];
         $post_page=$_POST['post_page'];
          $post_content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_content']);
        // $post_content= nl2br($post_content); 
         if($post_author==''){
           echo "<script>alert('You must fill all blank fields'); window.location('insert_post.php');</script>";
           exit();
         }
         else{
           move_uploaded_file($post_image_tmp,"../../images/$post_image");
           $sql="insert into post (page_id,post_title,post_author,post_image,post_keywords,post_catagory,post_content) values ('$post_page','$post_title','$post_author','$post_image','$post_keyword','$post_catagory','$post_content')";
           $result=mysqli_query($bd,$sql) or die("Error occured:in query".mysql_error());
           if(!$result){
             echo"<h2 style=\"color:red;position:absolute;top:0;left:400px;\">Your post wasnt posted something is worng</h2>";
           exit();
           }else{
             echo"<h2><script>alert('Your Post has been published successfully!')</script>";
           echo"<script>window.open('insert_post.php','_self')</script>";
          }
        }
    }
 ?>
    <!-- MAIN WRAPPER -->
    <div id="wrap" >
<?php 
   //echo $post_author;
   // echo $post_title;
    // echo $post_page;
     // echo $post_keyword;
     //  echo $post_content;
      //  echo $post_image;

?>
        <!-- MENU SECTION -->

        <!--END MENU SECTION -->

        <!--PAGE CONTENT -->
            <?php //include('include/content.php'); ?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div id="post_form">
                  <table>
                      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="post_form">


                            <tr>
                              <td><label>Post Title</label></td>
                              <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="post_title"></td>
                            </tr>  


                              <tr>
                                <td><label>Post Author</label></td>
                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="post_author"></td>
                              </tr>


                              <tr>
                                <td>  <label>Post Catagory</label></td>
                                  <td><select class="form-control" name="post_catagory">
                                    <?php
                                        $sql="select * from catagory";
                                        $result=mysqli_query($bd,$sql) or die("Error:".mysql_error());
                                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['name'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>

                                    <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>

                                  </select>
                                  </td>
                            </tr>    


                              <tr>
                                <td><label>Post keywords</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="post_keyword" placeholder="Enter text"></td>
                              </tr>



                            <tr>
                              <td><label>Post Image</label></td>
                              <td><input type="file"  name="post_image"/></td>
                           </tr>   

                            <tr>
                              <td><label>Select Page</label></td>
                              <td><select class="form-control" name="post_page">
                              <?php
                                $sql="select * from menu";
                                $result=mysqli_query($bd,$sql) or die("error".mysql_error());
                                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                ?>
                                  <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>


                                <?php
                                }
                              ?>
                              </select></td>
                           </tr>

                            <tr>
                              <td><label>Post Contents</label></td>
                              <td><textarea id="area1"  name="post_content" rows="10"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>  

                          <tr>
                            <td>Action Key</td>
                            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" onclick="nicEditors.findEditor('area1').saveContent();">Publish Now</button><button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                    </form>
                  </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!--END PAGE CONTENT -->

         <!-- RIGHT STRIP  SECTION -->
            <?php //include('include/right.php'); ?>
         <!-- END RIGHT STRIP  SECTION -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
    <!--END MAIN WRAPPER -->

    <!-- FOOTER -->
```

Comment: Make this change `echo $sql="insert into post (page_id,post_title,post_author,post_image,post_keywords,post_catagory,post_content) values ('$post_page','$post_title','$post_author','$post_image','$post_keyword','$post_catagory','$post_content')";  die;`  and update question with INSERT query you get.

Comment: Not related to the problem but rather to the question: Use newlines (Enter) when typing the question description and use "I" instead of "i" when referring to yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up `mysql` and `mysqli`. When you call `mysqli_query`, you have to prevent data with `mysqli_` functions too.

```
$post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string(nl2br($_POST['post_content'])); 
//                   ^
```

You should use `mysql_real_escape_string` for all string inputs to database which include, not just for the `content`.

Comment: Thanks Bro it works. I am really so fool. using mysql_real_escape_string() it was not working but its working perfectly using mysqli_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mysql_real_escape_string()` for all the values to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

> string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )

You have to add **connection link** as first argument of mysqli_real_escape_string()

```
$post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($bd, nl2br($_POST['post_content']));
```

Again

```
mysqli_query($bd,$sql) or die("Error occured:in query".mysql_error());
                                                       ^
```

Instead of

```
mysql_error()
```

use

```
mysqli_error($bd)
```